# string filtering on c++

Tags: c++, string, filter, replace

given a string literal in c++ i have to remove toxic words like stupid etc by ###.

Suppose i have my toxic words in an array like

```
char[][]={"...",".."...and more...}
```

and my string is like

```
char str[]="......."
```

any particular library func that could help me here.

thanks in advance for help

Comment: make sure you don't make any clbuttic mistakes!

Comment: Fitst advice don't use C constructs in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**boost string algorithms**

Example:

```
string str1="Hello Dolly, Hello World!"
replace_first(str1, "Dolly", "Jane"); // str1 == "Hello Jane, Hello World!"
replace_last(str1, "Hello", "Goodbye"); // str1 == "Hello Jane, Goodbye World!"
erase_all(str1, " "); // str1 == "HelloJane,GoodbyeWorld!"
erase_head(str1, 6); // str1 == "Jane,GoodbyeWorld!"
```

Download boost from [here](http://www.boost.org)

Documentation of this particular library is [here](http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/string_algo.pdf) (page 5 is about replace algorithms)